# Blender seems to reset keyframes

Tags: animation, keyframes

I am new to animating in blender and have a (what I think is) weird behaviour, which makes animating very frustrating and near impossible for me.

Please watch the uploaded .gif: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzk4Z.jpg

First I show my animation. After that i select one IK element in Pose Mode and play the animation again. Please notice that some positions of my bones just change in the animation. I did not modify anything. Since I bought the AK  model online I don't think I am allowed to share the blend file.

For easier comparision here are two pictures. One before clicking on the IK element and one after (same frame in the animation).

[image: After]

[image: Before]

This also happens everytime I move something in pose mode. Some positions change on other frames and I can't controll my animation.

Is this a known issue or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
uploaded the file without the ak. The arm rig and model is from this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xzLnkpBQUfA), so I hope it is Ok to share this here.

[image]

Steps on how to easily recreate an issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsRVj.jpg

Comment: It's difficult to guess, maybe you could share a copy of your file without the model, with arms and animation only. Anyway it could be a viewport refresh delay (due to bones constraints) or a wrong IK pole position or bad IK bones rest position, or some kind of constraints circular dependency.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response.I added the blend file in the post.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to reproduce the issue, I checked frames 1, 11 and 16, and everything is in the same place both with everything unselected or selecting the IK controller. For troubleshooting purposes, you could try to avoid using frame 0, and have your animation going from 1 to 41 instead of 0-40, sometimes frame 0 in Blender leads to unexpected behaviours. I'm supposing that the big jump between (actual) frame 0 and 1 is intended, and you know that jumping back leads to frame 1 and not to frame 0.

Comment: Hm, thank you nevertheless :). Yes, I have my origin position at frame 0 and start the actual animation at frame 1. I am going to try to get rid of frame 0 today and see if that solves the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, so I downloaded blender 2.8 a few days ago and just tried to open my animation with this version and it seems to be fine. I don't know what went wrong with my 2.79 version, maybe it is some problem with my local installation...

EDIT:

Nevermind, the problem still persists, however, now I am able to get rid of it by pressing STRG+Z sometimes.